# How to apply animation to character?

Tags: animation, rigging, mixamo

I have download animation from mixamo and trying to apply it on my mesh. The problem is my character is in A-pose and I suppose I need to assign rig from mixamo to my mesh with auto weights. But I can't do that when my character and rig doesn't have same position:
[image]
How can I apply that animation to my mesh?

Comment: first thing make sure that the armature is in rest pose, then select your mesh, switch to sculpt mode, activate the symmetry on X option, use the Pose brush to change the arm pose?

Comment: @moonboots what is the rest pose?

Comment: the armature's default pose

Comment: @moonboots how can I know armature's default pose? Is it 1 frame of animation?

Comment: Go into the Object Data panel and under Skeleton, click on Rest Position

Comment: @moonboots found it, thank you! I'll try to use it tomorrow.

Comment: @moonboots yeah, it works! Thank you! But one more question: can I scale bones without losing animation because I have a problem with too long bones?

Comment: Sure, no problem, but you need to scale the bone in Edit mode, not Pose mode

Comment: @moonboots hmm, I'm trying to change bone scale with mirror option activated but it doesn't work.

Comment: The bones need to have the good suffix, .L or _L for example for a left arm, otherwise there will be no mirroring

Comment: @moonboots understood, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing make sure that the armature is in rest pose, then select your mesh, switch to *Sculpt* mode, activate the symmetry on X option, use the *Pose* brush to change the arm pose:

[image]